# Basic probability - Proof

Tags: probability

I shall proof or rebut the following statement. I’d really like to do it myself but I have some questions and without some answers i feel like I cant go ahead.

Here is the problem

If $P(A)=P(B)=p$then $P(A \cap B) \le p^2$

My problem is that i don’t know if A and B are independent. 
If they are independent that it would be equal to $p^2$
But what if they are dependent. I seem to be missing some information

Can you point me in some direction?

Many thanks

Comment: What if $A=B$ and $P(A)=0.5$? Then, $$P(A\cap B)=0.5\not\leq0.25$$

Comment: Many thanks that did help a lot